# I've been past many sea snakes and sharks, but never encountered a shark with a purple fin. Is there a bug in my game?

Tags: candy-box-2

I also opened the Candy Box and finished the game. The purple shark fin is the last thing I need in my inventory.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep swimming and the purple finned shark will appear eventually

If you do not mind cheating, then you can get the game as text (on the "save"-tab), look for the entry `bool gridItemPossessedPurpleSharkFin=false` and change it to `bool gridItemPossessedPurpleSharkFin=true`

[More here](https://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Magical_purple_shark_fin)